# Defining types for svelte and sveltekit layout data

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In svelte (or sveltekit?) you can define a base `+layout.ts` file with a `load` function. The data returned from this function is seemingly accessible to all `+page.svelte` and `+layout.svelte` files as `data`. However I cannot figure out how to provide typing for this using Typescript.

Example
`+layout.ts`

```
// Return a "user" from the load function
export interface User {
  name: string,
  id: number
};

export const load = async () => {
  return {
    name: "User",
    id: 123
  }
}
```

Example of a `+layout.svelte` file

```html
<script lang="ts">
  // What should this be typed as? 
  // Sure it could be "User" but it seems svelte wants you to use generated typings? 
  // Like LayoutData or PageData?
  export let data;
</script>

<div>
  Hello {data.name}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have a somewhat recent version of the svelte language server and typescript plugin, they **automatically type everything for you in this situation**.

To type `load` and `data` correctly, you may need information about the directory structure (as SvelteKit operates with directory-based routes) and the file name (`+page`, `+layout`, `+server`...). SvelteKit used to just [generate the correct types in `./$types`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#generated-types), leaving to the developer the task of annotating.

However, as of March 9th, SvelteKit introduced a new feature: **Zero-effort type safety**. it now automatically inserts the correct type. I highly recommend you check out the [announcement post](https://svelte.dev/blog/zero-config-type-safety), it even shows an example on the old way to type `load` and `data`.